# C++ save ping in file with encoding

Tags: c++, character-encoding, ping

I use for making ping :

```
system("ping 127.0.0.1 > result.txt");
```

But my file doesn't show Russian text and I can't read info about ping. 
How can I set encoding for my `result.txt`?

Comment: this should be dependent on the language of your OS and is not a c++ related thing

Comment: On unix-like systems ping keeps sending it's packets forever. You can limit number of pings with -c option.

Comment: Pls post more detail about what results.txt actually contains. Could it be that your text viewer isn't properly configured? And post the platform (Windows?)

Comment: You might want to make sure that you write in utf-8. Cyrillic letters can be represented in that. Does this help you: http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2008/10/20/writing-utf-8-files-in-c/ ? If not, search for something like "c++ write utf-8 file". Note that the easiest way is if you find something that allows you to write your cyrillic letters in your code, but if you don't, you can surely get the utf-8 code for all of those.

Comment: Rather than letting a shell redirect create the output file, you're going to have to capture the output from `system` and write the file yourself. Otherwise this question is off topic for this site.